# Mapping the f keys to symbols not always working

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map all the function keys to the corresponding symbols. This is what I have put in my .vimrc:

```
:noremap! <F1> !
:noremap <F1> !
:noremap! <F2> @
:noremap <F2> @
:noremap! <F3> #
:noremap <F3> #
:noremap! <F4> $
:noremap <F4> $
:noremap! <F5> %
:noremap <F5> %
:noremap! <F6> ^
:noremap <F6> ^
:noremap! <F7> &
:noremap <F7> &
:noremap! <F8> *
:noremap <F8> *
:noremap! <F9> (
:noremap <F9> (
:noremap! <F10> )
:noremap <F10> )
:noremap! <F11> _
:noremap <F11> _
:noremap! <F12> +
:noremap <F12> +
```

Although it works with the insert, command-line and replace modes it does not work e.g with the r,f and t commands. There appears to be no conflict when I check with the :map command.

Comment: Maybe you can try some keyboard mapping softwares as a solution outside of Vim，the best case, which only applies to Vim.

Answer (score 2):

The vim help for `f` reads

```
f{char}         To [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right.  The
            cursor is placed on {char} |inclusive|.
            {char} can be entered as a digraph |digraph-arg|.
            When 'encoding' is set to Unicode, composing
            characters may be used, see |utf-8-char-arg|.
            |:lmap| mappings apply to {char}.  The CTRL-^ command
            in Insert mode can be used to switch this on/off
            |i_CTRL-^|.
```

Based on this, I think you would need to also do

```
:lnoremap <F1> !
:lnoremap <F2> @
" etc
```

I also found that I had to use `CTRL-^` in insert mode as the manual suggests before the mappings would apply to `f` and `t` (the default was to ignore the `lmap`ings).

Comment: After `CTRL-^` it works for the `r` command however not for `f` or `t`. I tried the same with non f-key mappings with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

As Johnmastroberti pointed out, indeed you need to use lmap to achieve your goal.

The `CTRL-^` trick actually controls [iminsert](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27iminsert%27) variable. You can set it manually with

```
:set iminsert=1
```

But the problem you can struggle with is **clever-f** plugin as it replaces default `f` behaviour and (I can be wrong here but didn't find such option) do not allow to use lmapping.